# How to filter for localized fields in the Commercetools ProductProjectionsSearch API?

Tags: commercetools, sphere.io

I tried to filter for the brand but never got any results back. Brand was a localized text attribute on my products. I used the following variations:

`variants.attributes.brand:"LEGO"`
`variants.attributes.brand.de:"LEGO"`
`masterVariant.attributes.brand:"LEGO"`
`masterVariant.attributes.brand.de:"LEGO"`

I'm using the node.js-SDK btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the pattern for filters on attributes of localized text type is

`variants.attributes.{name}.{lang}:"{value}"`

To analyze why this is not working for you, please create a support ticket on https://support.commercetools.com

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: We figured the problem out (via a support ticket). The field has to be searchable in ALL product types. Otherwise none is found. I can work around that but it is not very intuitive.